# How to create a designated comment page with custom fields

Tags: comments

I'm creating a site where I want to use the comment box to auto-generate a FAQ page.

In essence, when a comment is posted it won't appear on the same page as the comment box.  Instead, it will be displayed on a secondary "Faq" page.  On the page editor, I'd like to simple add a custom field where I input the post ID of the other page, pass and use that to generate a page that is composed entirely of the comments from the parent page.

Here's what the relevant portion of my code looks like at the moment:

```
<?php
$faqpagenum = get_post_meta($post->post_parent, 'faqpagenum', true);
if (isset($faqpagenum) {
        $faqs = get_comments(array('post_id'=>$faqpagenum));
        wp_list_comments('',$faqs);
}?>
```

Unfortunately, every time I try this, I keep getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in..."

With the reference line being the line beginning with `$faqpagenum`.

So, what am I doing wrong?  I'm at the point where I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

EDIT: I'm also considering using `wp_get_post_parent_id` to automatically pull the parent ID and pull the comments without the need for a custom field, so if you have an idea along those lines, I'm all ears.

Comment: You've a syntax error in `if (isset($faqpagenum) {`. Try for example `if ( ! empty( $faqpagenum ) ) {` instead.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  That works!  I knew I had to be missing something obvious.